# MKR Zero not showing up in WIN10 device manager / Arduino IDE cannot detect port / COM

Tags: arduino-ide, usb, windows, mkrzero

I'm new to Arduino and hope you guys can give some advise.

I bought MKR Zero a few days before and tried to connect to my Win10 laptop. I can see the LED on the board is on, but the Arduino IDE cannot detect it. the "Port" is grey out. I tried 2 laptops which also Win10 but same situation happen. I tried different USB cables I had.

I checked the device manager in the control panel, there is no "Unknown device" under the USB port but also no MKR showing up. I don't know what to do.

I'm not sure if it is Win10 problem...Please kindly advise, thank you very much!!

Comment: Try a different cable?

Comment: You can try out this reference for your problem [How To Disable Driver Signature Enforcement in Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71YAIw7_-kg) . Also check the connections.

Comment: i bought another 2 cables and same situation still happen

Comment: did you install the SAMD boards package? https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoMKRZero

Comment: yes i did - now the IDE can let me select MKR Zero board, but the "Port.  >" is grey out. I still cannot select the port that is connecting to the board

Comment: thank you kaviranga - i tried to disable the enforcement but still cannot connect to my board

Comment: Have you tried runnng the ArduinoIDE as admnistrator?

Comment: thank you Codebreaker007 - just tried to run as administrator, but the Port still grey out

Comment: Are you sure that you are using usb data cables, if the device shows not up in device manager you probably use a "charging only" usb cable used for mobile phones or similar to load. Can you see the MKR Zero in device manager?

Comment: thank you Codebreaker007 - no I cannot see it in device manager even if i plug it in my laptop, so maybe i am really using "charging only" usb cable...I will go to some shops and buy data cable and try again, thank you for your advice!

Comment: Take your laptop and your Arduino with you The right cable will let the Arduino show up in device manager (most sellers do not even know there are different types of usb cables on the market. Report back your proceedings

Comment: hello - i went to the shop and bought the "sync and charge" cable and tried on 3 different Win10 laptops, still same situation happen - the LED light is on but nothing detected in the device manager.
I think I will just simply go back to the shop and return the Arduino board...

Comment: hello - I went back to the hardware shop and they verified that my MKRZero is really not working...they changed another one to me and it works now...thank you everyone for your kind suggestion! I will close this question now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hardware itself problem. Went to the shop and changed the board to me and now works.